# How can I know if a json body has content?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a filter to do some code if the body has body or not, because the enrich mediator cant work with a null body, but I dont know the expression

I tried boolean($body) but doesn't work

```
<filter regex="default_regex" source="boolean($body)">
<then>
    <enrich>
       <source clone="true" type="body"/>
       <target property="payload" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
 </then>
 <else>
    <log level="full"/>
 </else>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you update the regex to true and give it a try.

```
<filter regex="true" source="boolean($body)">
<then>
    <enrich>
       <source clone="true" type="body"/>
       <target property="payload" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
 </then>
 <else>
    <log level="full"/>
 </else>
```

And if it doesn't get the json payload, try assigning it to a property and do filter.

```
<property name="JsonBody" expression="json-eval($.)/>
<filter regex="true" source="boolean($ctx:JsonBody)">
<then>
    <enrich>
       <source clone="true" type="body"/>
       <target property="payload" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
 </then>
 <else>
    <log level="full"/>
 </else>
```

Thanks